# Ecquis as a modifying adjective

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, grammar-identification, adjective

I'm unsure of the bolded part of the sentence:

Haec prima sententia est, quam ut clarius explicemus, diligenter attendendum venit, **ecquis iuxta hanc sententiam tum in electionis tum in reprobationis decreto ordo & concatenatio inter actus divinos sibi invicem succenturiatos ab iis statuatur.**

Is ecquis an adjective modifying ordo?

Comment: Where is this passage from?

Answer (score 7):

[Ecquis](https://latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries/?t=lsn15119) can be used as an interrogative adjective. Here I would read *attendendum* as calling for an indirect question clause.

attendendum ... ecquis ... ordo & concatenatio ... statuatur

We must consider whether any arrangement/order and sequence is established/posited